# Remove quotes inside php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I avoid the error next to `</object>"`?

I need to remove a bunch of single cotes in my database and my problem is the **"** next to `</object>`...

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts SET post_content = REPLACE post_content,"</object>"' ,'</object>'");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php or if you really want to remove them http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: You don't need to remove quotes. You can either escape them or use prepared statements.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario can you point me out an example, please? I am driving nuts...

Comment: @Alex - First of all, the standard SQL delimiter for strings is the single quote. If you'd use single quotes inside double quotes then there'd be no need to escape anything. Secondly, that's basic PHP syntax: `$name = 'O\'Brian';`

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you seem to be missing the parentheses around the `REPLACE` string function, but you can put quotes inside of quotes if you escape them with `\`

```
REPLACE(post_content, \"'</object>'\", \"</object>\")
```

Comment: I've already tried that solution like this: `$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, \'</content>\"\', \'</content>\' ))";` but I still got an erros and the query doesn't run. This is strange because I can run this query on pypmyadmin but not inside my php file...

Comment: @Alex you don't have to escape the single quotes, only the double quotes

Comment: but I am using this on a php file and it wont update my database... ` $wpdb = "Update $wpdb->posts SET post_content = Replace(post_content, '</object>"', '</object>')";//Update`

Comment: @Alex you never actually run the query, and that is not even valid PHP syntax

Comment: @Alex unfortunately, you seem to be lacking some very basic knowledge to get this to work.  I would brush up on PHP/MySQL syntax, especially for handling strings.  I *think* that what you want to do is `$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,\"'</object>'\"' ,'</object>')");`

Comment: I really thank your help but I have solved my problem in other way. Your solution didn't work with me but I'm sure that this will be useful to others. Thanks